# Does a title always have to be a question, ended with a question mark?

Tags: discussion, title

I have seen some titles that are not real questions, just telling the issue that will be dealt with.
Is it a good practice? Is it mandatory for titles to be questions and end with question marks?

EDIT : I'm aware this might be a duplicate of [Are non-question titles desirable or undesirable?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/are-non-question-titles-desirable-or-undesirable) but I did not find this one with the keywords *title*, *question* and *mark*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, it's not mandatory

Ideally, question titles should describe the thing that's being asked. Usually that takes the form of a question, but it needn't always.

A good, top-of-mind example is [Help me find this robot cartoon character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145546/31051). Yes, that title could be re-written as "Who is this robot cartoon character?", but the benefit is marginal at best.

Story-id questions are also good examples; a question on the front page right now is [Sci fi movie where Earth's most influential figures are revealed to be alien androids](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145574/31051). I ask you: what benefit is gained from rewriting that as "What is the title of a sci fi movie where etc."? Especially when you consider that most, if not all, story-id questions could be re-written in that way, it just becomes redundant noise.

Clarity is more important than nitpicky rules.